# How do I catch the empty result from query in javascript and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

Yesterday, I knew the big problem in my express server.

The problem is from DB query.

This is problem code.

```js
  var query = "select * from automation_script where id = ?";
  conn.query('use test');
  conn.query(query, req.params.id, function (error, result, fields) {
   if (error) {
    //이 부분은 오직 잘못된 쿼리일 경우에만 접근
    console.log('Update_DB error' + error);
   } else {
    console.log(result);
    if(result === null || result === ''){
     console.log('How do I get this?????');
    }
    console.log(result[0].title); //error because result is empty.
    
    //(*) 페이지 렌더링
    res.render('screenModify', {
     title: 'Test Automation',
     id: result[0].id,
     txt1: result[0].title,
     txt2: result[0].subject,
     txt3: result[0].script
    });
   }
  });
```

If sql query is wrong, this code catch the error.

But sql query is right, however, if the result is empty, server is bomb~!

So, I want to catch when the query result is empty.

Please, Help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put this snippet of code in try catch block.

Comment: I solve it!! Thanks you!!! 꾸벅꾸벅!